# My HTML footer won't move downward

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my footer to move to the bottom right. It currently is the only thing on the page that doesn't move AT ALL when I resize the browser, much less to the bottom of the page or to the right. I'm new to HTML, mostly doing this as an output for a data science project. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 


<style>
html {
    background: url("https://lh3.ggpht.com/TOsicwUVM6bKoB1_u_5noea0kkFAegkAdBFQcmTXhwKrN5485URcl0IWxgjldjd59A=h900") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
body { height: 100%;}
#nonFooter { position: relative; min-height: 100%;}
* html #nonFooter { height: 100%;}
#Footer { position: relative; margin-top: -7.5em; }

</style>

<body>
 
    <div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="header">
            <h3 style ="color:#FFFFFF" class="text-muted">Headerthing</h3>
        </div>
 
        <div>
            <h1 align="center" style ="color:#FFFFFF">Predict tool</h1>
            <p class="lead"></p>
        </div>
        <div style ="width: 300px; margin: 130px auto 0 auto; ">
        <div style ="color:#FFFFFF;">
           <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
            </form>

        <form action="/action_page.php">
  Instagram Handle:<br>
  <input type="text" name="handle"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
        </div> 
        </div>


</div>
 
<footer class="site-footer">
    <p style="color:white">Founders: Charles Barkley, Hakeem the Dream and Shaqs fat ass </p>
</footer>


</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: So you want it at the very bottom?

Comment: that would be amazing. To the right would be a huge bonus

Comment: Please do not TYPE YOUR TITLE IN ALL CAPS. There's no reason to SHOUT here. When you look at the main page's list of questions, you don't see any (except yours) in ALL CAPS, and the reasons for that are a) it won't get you help any faster; b) it makes text more difficult to read and parse; and c) it's extremely rude and annoying to have people SHOUT AT YOU. Show some respect and common courtesy, and don't come here and SHOUT, any more than we would come to your office or house and SHOUT AT YOU when asking you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `footer` is already at the bottom of the page.

"By moving it `down`" I assume you're referring to the `margins` that are automatically assigned to the `<p>` tag by default.
You can remove these, and get the text the appear at the **absolute** bottom-right with the following CSS:

```
    .site-footer p {
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

I've created a updated showcase in [Fiddle Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/ejcmk7xb/).

Note that `position: absolute` in conjunction with `bottom: 0`. This will make  your footer stay at the bottom-right of the **visible** screen. The element will always be visible, even if you haven't scrolled to its location yet.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Awesome but one question, where do i add the part to point to a CSS file? I've saved a file called "mystyle.css" with your given code into the same folder, what code snippet do I add to the html file to point to it correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: You're using an internal stylesheet as it is -- just chuck the above code in your `<style>` tags. Alternatively (and preferably), I recommend you look into [**W3School's How-To CSS**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) article, which explains how to reference stylesheets externally, and provides a bit more reference on CSS :)